# What is the math / function behind the wiggle expression in After Effects?

Tags: math, graphics, perlin-noise, after-effects

Looking at the [docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/expression-language-reference.html), I see that it takes `octaves` as an argument leading me to think it might be based on perlin noise?

My guess would be,

```
wiggle( freq, amp, octaves, amp_mult, t )
{
   current_time = t + time;
   noiseDetail( octaves, amp_mult );
   return noise( current_time * freq ) * amp;
}
```

where [noise()](https://processing.org/reference/noise_.html) and [noiseDetail()](https://processing.org/reference/noiseDetail_.html) are similar to the Processing implementations linked.